# Need to create an excel file by using t-sql code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have to create dynamically named excel file using t-sql code. I tried many searching and trying but couldn't find the solution please help me. I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: Your toolset matters a lot. If you can use SSIS and a scheduled job, it should be pretty easy. If you are embedding t-sql into C# or VB, it should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this in your frontend, not in your sql code.

But I found a tutorial [here](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/05/04/generate-an-excel-xls-spreadsheet-from-t-sql-in-sql-server/).

Tjeu

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that you can load custom dll's into sql server and then use them like stored procedures. Don't know for sure if this was already possible in sql server 2005. Never tried this myself.

Aspose has a good set of libs for creating / reading office documents from .net,
unfortunately they are not free.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an SSIS package that you can run to create the Excel file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

But here is an explanation on how to manipulate Excel from SQL server

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-excel-workbench/